# Установка fibers глобально в Node.js для Vuetify

Tags: node.js, npm, vuetify

Хочу установить fibers вот так

**npm install fibers -D**

Но получаю ошибки:

gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:275:12)

gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362

gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"

gyp ERR! cwd D:\Курсы\Vue\spa-project\node_modules\fibers

gyp ERR! node -v v13.11.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7

gyp ERR! not ok

node-gyp exited with code: 1

Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--

Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`

gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362

gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"

gyp ERR! cwd D:\Курсы\Vue\spa-project\node_modules\fibers

gyp ERR! node -v v13.11.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7

gyp ERR! not ok

node-gyp exited with code: 1

Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--

Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^4.36.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! fibers@4.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@4.0.2 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-17T19_30_41_232Z-debug.log

Node.js последней версии. Бьюсь уже три дня. Нужен для зависимостей в Vuetify.

Вот такие установки уже сделал:

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

npm install --global node-gyp

Ось Win10 x64

Помогите плиз...

Comment: я бы, для начала, убрал крилицу с пути `gyp ERR! cwd D:\Курсы\Vue\spa-project\node_modules\fibers`

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо. Заработало